# Executing a query --- Hibernate + Spring

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, orm

I am using spring and hibernate together.

Can any body suggest me how can i execute a simple query?

For example, I want to execute "select count(*) from USER_DETAILS";

Thanks,
Narendra

Answer (score 1):

Hiii...
Use criteria and projection together. Projection

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(USER_DETAILS.class);
ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
projList.add(Projections.countDistinct("Id"));
crit.setProjection(projList);
```

crit.list will give you count. This is simple hibernate code you can figure out spring + hibernat with this example.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is a Object-Relational Mapping tool. You first map a User object to USER_DETAILS table and then you write [HQL (Hibernate Query Language)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-aggregation) against the mapped User object (not USER_DETAILS table). For e.g you can write the query you have posted as below using HQL.

> select count(user) from User user;